# How to get 5 x 5 mm^2 in siunitx package

Tags: siunitx

I am started using `siunitx` package and I want something like,

```
5 x 5 mm^2
```

so I used below syntax,

```
\SI[output-product = \times]{312 x 112}{mm^2}
```

However with this I am getting,

```
5mm^2 x 5mm^2
```

Notice, the `mm^2` appearing twice. Is it possible to get one `mm^2`?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can get one. As `siunitx` is clever it squares the unit itself, so you have to give just one mm without any power.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \SI[product-units=power]{5 x 5}{\mm}
\end{document}
```

[image]